# Having trouble populating tableView using Firebase/Firestore in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

This is my first time working with a cloud database and I'm looking for a little bit of guidance here as I'm relatively new to programming, and Firestore in particular.

I'm trying to `get()` all of my document data inside of my `viewDidLoad` and store it inside of a dictionary so that I can use it later in the `tableView dataSource` methods to populate my `tableView` Sections and Rows.

I'm working on a gym/workout log app and I inputted some dummy data for Days and Workouts Collections, so my dictionary prints out like this...

```
dataDict = ["Monday": ["Chest", "Arms"], "Wednsday": ["Legs", "Arms"], "Tuesday": ["Back"]]
```

But I'm having trouble using this data to populate the fields because if I try to print out the results of `dataDict` outside of the `dateWorkoutRequest` function, like inside of my `dataSource` methods, I get an empty dictionary. Is my `tableView.reloadData()` in the wrong place? Should I be using a dictionary to parse my data or is that a bad idea?

Here is my data structure and the relevant code...

```
/users/mi9P3TrLwkQejYo3oDIu/Days/WZ3Q6LDuu1kja5Rc/Workouts/BpLGFREoJNzNQW
```

[image]

[image]

```
var daysArray = [String]()
var dayIdArray = [String]()
var dataDict : [String:[String]] = [:]

//MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    vcBackgroundImg()
    navConAcc()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        self.userIdRef = user!.uid
        self.colRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days")

        self.dateWorkoutRequest()
    }
}

func dateWorkoutRequest(){
    self.colRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err
        {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
        }
        else {
            //Appending all Days collection documents with a field of "dow" to daysarray...
            for dayDocument in snapshot!.documents {
                self.daysArray.append(dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? "")
                self.dayIdArray.append(dayDocument.documentID)

                Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayDocument.documentID)/Workouts/").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                    if let err = err
                    {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                    }
                    else {
                        //Assigning all Workouts collection documents belonging to selected \(dayDocument.documentID) to dictionary dataDict...
                        for document in snapshot!.documents {

                            if self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] == nil {
                                self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] = [document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? ""]
                            } else {
                                self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""]?.append(document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? "")
                            }
                            print(self.dataDict)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.dayCount =  snapshot?.count ?? 0
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to put the self.tableView.reloadData() just after the line that you append document in the array.

I think that it's interesting you put DispatchQueue.main.async block in the reloadData too.

Like this:

```
func dateWorkoutRequest(){
            self.colRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                if let err = err
                {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                }
                else {
                    //Appending all Days collection documents with a field of "dow" to daysarray...
                    for dayDocument in snapshot!.documents {
                        self.daysArray.append(dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? "")
                        self.dayIdArray.append(dayDocument.documentID)

                        Firestore.firestore().collection("/users/\(self.userIdRef)/Days/\(dayDocument.documentID)/Workouts/").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
                            if let err = err
                            {
                                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                            }
                            else {
                                //Assigning all Workouts collection documents belonging to selected \(dayDocument.documentID) to dictionary dataDict...
                                for document in snapshot!.documents {

                                    if self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] == nil {
                                        self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""] = [document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? ""]
                                    } else {
                                        self.dataDict[dayDocument.data()["dow"] as? String ?? ""]?.append(document.data()["workout"] as? String ?? "")
                                    }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.dayCount =  snapshot?.count ?? 0

                }
            }
        }
```